# Part of jQuery's callback handling undoes my statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX via jQuery to make a get request. Upon success, I place the result into a div:

```
$.get("content.php", function(result) {
  $('#content').html(result);
```

The content I'm requesting itself is HTML and has two divs, `#article_name` and `#article_content`. After it loads, I check if `#article_content` has any children. If it doesn't, I add a `<p>` block:

```
  if (!$('#article_content').children().length) {
    $('#article_content').html('<p>(Click here to enter text)</p>');
  }
}
```

This works, until JavaScript leaves the callback function. That is, after my conditional, the `<p>` block is added; but as I step through in Chrome's inspector, it dives into jQuery's callback section, and by the time it's through the `<p>` block disappears.

I've run my conditional in the console to make sure it's not the problem.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. It is difficult to help without seeing more of your code.

Comment: i would try it with append() instead of html()

Comment: that didn't do it. If I run the conditional code from the console, it works. it has something to do with the callback part of $.get.

Comment: Could you give your full code to see how and when you do call your function?

Comment: I just had an ordering wrong, I was updating the content after the conditional. My apologies!

I'm new to SO, should I delete this question? What's the appropriate course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the ordering wrong - I placed my conditional before the code that updated the content area.

Should I delete this question?